# “Gehen” with genitive?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, genitive

I saw this in *Der treffende Ausdruck*:

> Die Nachbarin grüßte ihn kurz und ging ihres Weges, aber der Kollege unterhielt sich mit ihm, während sie auf den Bus warteten.

I’ve never seen a *gehen* plus genitive construction before. From the context I assume it just means *she went on her way* but I’m curious as to why one would use the genitive there, if it sets a certain tone, and if using *gehen* + genitive is appropriate/necessary in some contexts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Congratulations, you have stumbled upon an idiomatic expression. Check the [Duden page for *Weg*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Weg) to find a mention of it under *Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter*.

*Seines Weges gehen* is a fixed expression meaning to physically walk along one’s ways. It should not be confused with *seinen Weg gehen* which can also be used in the metaphoric sense of *sticking to one’s path*.

I am not aware of any other constructions that use *gehen* plus genitive. However, it is paralleled in ‘Wohin des Weges?’, a now frozen expression for ‘where are you going?’